# Animated Sliding Window

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a (flex) container with two divs (**DIV 1**, **DIV 2**) that are arranged next to each other.

In the default state, only **DIV 1** is visible. **DIV 1** uses the entire width of the container.

I would like to implement a sliding window that lets **DIV 2** slide in from the right with a transition/animation. **DIV 1** should (if possible) still be present in DOM.

The **main challenge** for me is in the 2. transition/animation.
Currently, I tested several ways to temporarily hide the DIV 1 in CSS. Like using *display: none* OR *absolute: position* with *left: -999px*.

However, it never worked for the 2. transition/animation. Any clever ideas?

Ah, it's an Angular app. But pure HTML/CSS/JS advice is totally fine.
3

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below. Hover the container to see the animation:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container > * {
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
.one {background: red}
.two {background: blue}


.container:hover > * {
  transform: translate(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good approach! But any clever idea for a transition if DIV 2 is already visible on the screen with e.g. 40% (see the middle container of the image). Basically 2 transitions: Increase DIV 2 to 100% & slide DIV 2 to full screen? Or is there a way with only one smooth transition?